# C# Extreme duplication of log entries in database table

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, database-design, duplicates

This C# class is making a lot of duplicates in my Oracle DB table, how do i optimize fix it to not do that, but still make logs / error reports? I have included the code for the methods that creates the logs.

### Screenshot of duplicates in the DB table:

[image: Duplicates in Database table]

### CreateLogEntryForAgent()

```
  public static ApplicationLogEntry CreateLogEntryForAgent(string logText, LogTypes type) {
        int agentId = 0;
        int applicationVersionId = 0;

        if(Environment.CurrentAgent.Value != null)
            agentId = Environment.CurrentAgent.Value.Id;

        if(Environment.CurrentApplication.Value != null &&
            Environment.CurrentApplication.Value.GetCurrentVersion() != null)
            applicationVersionId = Environment.CurrentApplication.Value.GetCurrentVersion().Id;

        return new ApplicationLogEntry(DateTime.Now,
                                       agentId,
                                       SystemVars.GetComputerName(),
                                       applicationVersionId,
                                       logText,
                                       type);
    }
```

### CreateErrorLogEntry()

```
 public static ApplicationLogEntry CreateErrorLogEntry(Exception exception, string applicationState) {
        if(exception == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");

        int agentId = 0;
        int applicationVersionId = 0;

        if(Environment.CurrentAgent.Value != null)
            agentId = Environment.CurrentAgent.Value.Id;

        if(Environment.CurrentApplication.Value != null &&
           Environment.CurrentApplication.Value.GetCurrentVersion() != null)
            applicationVersionId = Environment.CurrentApplication.Value.GetCurrentVersion().Id;

        return new ApplicationLogEntry(DateTime.Now,
                                       agentId,
                                       SystemVars.GetComputerName(),
                                       applicationVersionId,
                                       ErrorLogging.CreateExceptionDescription(exception, SystemVars.GetAssemblyFullName(), applicationState, true),
                                       LogTypes.Error);
    }
```

### CreateReportLogEntry

```
public static ApplicationLogEntry CreateReportLogEntry(XmlDocument report) {
        if(report == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("report");

        int agentId = 0;
        int applicationVersionId = 0;

        if(Environment.CurrentAgent.Value != null)
            agentId = Environment.CurrentAgent.Value.Id;

        if(Environment.CurrentApplication.Value != null &&
           Environment.CurrentApplication.Value.GetCurrentVersion() != null)
            applicationVersionId = Environment.CurrentApplication.Value.GetCurrentVersion().Id;

        return new ApplicationLogEntry(DateTime.Now,
                                       agentId,
                                       SystemVars.GetComputerName(),
                                       applicationVersionId,
                                       report.OuterXml,
                                       LogTypes.Report);
    }
```

### One example of method calling

```
if(SystemVars.IsProductionEnvironment())
            ApplicationLog.LogEvent(ApplicationLogEntry.CreateLogEntryForAgent("Application Closed", LogTypes.Notification));
```

Comment: If they are entirely duplicates you have 2 obvious choices and maybe some less obvious ones, 1 is that when youve assigned the logging youve done it multiple times or added and not removed as necessary so for a single event its called more than once. Or you save a copy of the last error logged and if duplicated maybe up a counter.. and then the moment its no longer the same drop a message of "previous message repeated x times" for clarity

Comment: I would have thought that your logging code is not the problem. If you are duplicating logging entries then it suggests to me that the issue with with the code that calls the logger?

Comment: The method is called every time i synchronize employees mails with a synchronizer program, I added the code for this